# fclose crashes when closing my recent created file

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

I'm trying to create a log file for each program execution.

```
char * createLogFile(char *filename) {
  char path[100] = "logs_folder/";
  char text[100] = "";
  strcpy(text, filename);
  strcat(path, text);
  strcat(path, ".txt");
  FILE *logFile;
  logFile = fopen(path, "w");
  fclose(logFile);
  return text;
}
```

The problemm comes when I'm debugging this code piece, logFile is always null. And the program crashesh when it reaches `fclose()`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTF41.png)

it takes me to this line of invalid_parameter.cpp:

```
if (IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE))
{
 __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_INVALID_ARG);
}
```

The path is correct, why isn't the file creating? Why does it crash?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The if nullcheck was a debug code that I pasted :(. The whole error is without that check and return – I've just edited the post, sorry.

Comment: Then the answer was in the debugging code! So my comment is: please test whether logFile is null, and if it is, please show the output of perror or strerror.

Comment: logFile is indeed null.

Comment: @SergeBallesta logs_folder/log_2016-05-20-(10-37).txt: no such a file or directory.

Comment: Does the directory `logs_folder` exists in current directory? If it does not, it is not created and you get this error

Comment: @Patxiku In your case [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) returns NULL because the file cannot be opened for some reason. So check if `fopen` return NULL and if yes, inspect [`errno`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) take some appropriate action and d'ont call `fclose`.

Comment: The point it that it should create that file. Isn't that how `fopen(path,"w")` work? If  it exists open to write, else create the file to write.

Comment: Hmm, you should try to show what is the current directory at the moment you call fopen. Alternatively what OS and file system are you using? But I would be surprised by an underlying file system issue because even Windows accepts it...

Comment: Windows 10 x64. NTFS

Comment: @Patxiku you can also step into `fopen`with the debugger, this may help you to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Patxiku the current directory may not be what you expect. Use [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) to check.

Comment: @Patxiku the crash occurs because you call `fclose` with a NULL parameter. That crash is expected. The actual question is **Why is fopen unable to open my file**.

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz can't get `GetCurrentDirectoy`working.

Comment: For test purposes, temporarily put in a complete, absolute path.  The 'current directory' is an antiquated annoyance.

Comment: You mean, "C:\path\path\path\path\log_files\lalalal.txt" or just "log_files\lalala.txt" ?

Comment: @Patxiku _can't get `GetCurrentDirectoy` working_: be more explicit.

Comment: it saves me numbers, not path: `TCHAR Buffer[BUFSIZE];
   DWORD dwRet;  dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, Buffer);`

Comment: Ok, I might find the path error. using VIsual studio debug tools doesn't launch the compiled exe in the same directory as other ones.

Answer (score 1):

The code sequence

```
strcpy(text, filename);
strcat(path, text);
strcat(path, ".txt");
```

is simply dangerous, since you append to a stack based buffer (`path`) unverified input string (`filename`)... Possibly the result is a stack overwrite which destroys your `logFile` variable...

If you stick to MS paltform, use `strcat_s` and `strcpy_s`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) or at least do some length checking.

Also, you return the address of a local stack based variable which gets destroyed after the function exits.

Comment: The `if null`check was a debug code that I pasted :(. The whole error is without that check and `return`

Answer (score 1):

your program should not go to `fclose` if it is always null.

Are you sure that the string `text` is long enough?
Why don't you use a `strlen()` of `path` and `filename` to get the minimum char you need?

```
int len = strlen(path) + strlen(filename) + 5; //5 == ".txt" & '\0'
char text[len] = "";
```

And are you sure the path you set is right?

Comment: The path is alright. if I try to do `char[len]` expression must have a constant value.

Comment: You can malloc your string so.